# Using uniqueidentifiers/guids as custom properties in log4net

Tags: .net, log4net, uniqueidentifier

I'm trying to add a custom property which is a guid, but it gives me this error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Failed to
>   convert parameter value from a String
>   to a Guid. --->
>   System.InvalidCastException: Invalid
>   cast from 'System.String' to
>   'System.Guid'.

I specify this in the config:

```
<parameter>
<parameterName value="@id" />
<dbType value="Guid" />
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
<conversionPattern value="%X{id}" />
</layout>
</parameter>
```

The actual code (snippet) i use is this:

```
        Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        if (defaultLogger.IsEnabledFor(level))
        {
            var loggingEvent = new LoggingEvent(ThisDeclaringType,
 defaultLogger.Repository, defaultLogger.Name, level, message, exception);
            loggingEvent.Properties["Id"] = guid;
```

Any help please? :) The id field in the database is defined as a uniqueidentifier NOT NULL, but it does not have the primary key contraint.

Comment: why do you want a guid? Is this to provide some sort of context?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For your example the following should work:

```xml
<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@Oid" />
  <dbType value="Guid" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawPropertyLayout">
    <key value="Id" />
  </layout>
</parameter>
```

Important is you rename @id to something else otherwise you will get Null values in database even if you try to insert strings,

And then use RawPropertyLayout to store, cus you do not need to do a convertion.

Comment: For clarity, <key> is the name of the value to lookup in the LoggingEvent Properties collection.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Download the source code of log4.net

**2.** Change the function `FormatValue` inside the file `log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.cs` like this:

```
virtual public void FormatValue(IDbCommand command, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
        {
            // Lookup the parameter
            IDbDataParameter param = (IDbDataParameter)command.Parameters[m_parameterName];

            // Format the value
            object formattedValue = Layout.Format(loggingEvent);

            // If the value is null then convert to a DBNull
            if (formattedValue == null)
            {
                formattedValue = DBNull.Value;
            }

            if (param.DbType == System.Data.DbType.Guid)
            {
                param.Value = new Guid(formattedValue.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                param.Value = formattedValue;
            }
        }
```

then it works!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a general-purpose GUID property, you can do the following:

```
    private void ConfigureLog4Net()
    {
        // adds a global custom log4net property
        log4net.GlobalContext.Properties[nameof(Guid.NewGuid)] = new NewGuidWrapper();

        // configures log4net by XML configurations from a .config file
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    }

    private class NewGuidWrapper
    {
        // will return new GUID every time it's called
        public override string ToString() => Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
```

and then you can call the property in the following way:

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <!-- if you want to format the layout as a GUID followed by a message  -->
  <conversionPattern value="%property{NewGuid} %m%n" />
</layout>
```

You can also use such type of layout for a custom DB parameter as it's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12140226/9093605).