# log4net inserting (null) into custom column

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

Added a custom column as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139486/log4net-how-to-add-a-custom-field-to-my-logging). Things are working fine when ever I log something into this column using the code line

```
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["CustomColumn"] = "Custom value";
```

But if I pass null instead as below

```
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["CustomColumn"] = null;
```

this is logged as **(null)**(a string null included in brakets). This also happens if I do not log at all, like I comment the code as shown below.

```
//log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["CustomColumn"] = null;
```

So the question is, is there a way to make it actually null in the database, instead of a string - (null). I am using ms sql server 2008 r2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["CustomColumn"] = DBNull.Value;
```

Comment: Hi Szeki, DBNull.Value is resulting in empty string - '' but not null.

Answer (score 5):

I  have modified the insert statement of the commandText value in Web.config file to

```
"INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception],[BrowserCapabilities]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, 
        @logger, @message, @exception, CASE WHEN @BrowserCapabilities = '' OR @BrowserCapabilities = '(null)' THEN NULL ELSE @BrowserCapabilities END )"
```

Now this works fine.

Comment: Ingenious! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer "NULLIF" over "CASE WHEN" in this case.  This alternative still requires modifying the insert statement of the commandText value in the Web.config file, but it is more efficient:

```
INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception],[BrowserCapabilities]) 
VALUES (@log_date,@thread,@log_level,@logger,@message,@exception,NULLIF(@BrowserCapabilities,'(null)')"
```