# How to dynamically add a value to a field using log4net

Tags: c#, asp.net, log4net

I am working on log4net for the first time and I got it to working. But some of the fields iin the database where I am logging are empty. I want to make use of those. For example FileName (db column) is (null). And I have its parameter set up in config file like this

```
<parameter>
    <parameterName value="@filename" />
     <dbType value="String" />
     <size value="200" />
     <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
     <conversionPattern value="%X{cFileName}" />
    </layout>
</parameter>
```

I want to use this above parameter with a dynamic value sent from the asp.net code. And I see this below part as an appender and I am not really sure what this is for. Please suggest. Thanks in advance!!

```
<conversionPattern value="%d [%t] %-5level %logger%nCustom Message: %X{cMessage}%nSystem Message: %m%n" />
```

Comment: How are you setting the value for cFileName?

Comment: @sgmoore I am not sure how can I pass cFileName from the code? Because when logging, All I am sending is a Message and Exception. Ex: logger.LogInfo("Start App", null) or logger.LogError( "Error: , ex). I want to add something like cFileName too.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139486/log4net-how-to-add-a-custom-field-to-my-logging?rq=1

Comment: Very well @sgmoore. I really appreciate the help. This is exactly what I wanted to know. Can you please post your above comment as an answer. I would like to vote it. Thanks a lot