# Log4Net, how to add a custom field (variable) to my logging

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-appender

I'm referring to the excellent post :

[Log4Net, how to add a custom field to my logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139486/log4net-how-to-add-a-custom-field-to-my-logging)

But it doesn't give me the entire solution.

No problem to log  a string like "This is a test", but If I want to log a variable, it's responding (null).

Here is my snipped code not working:

```
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["versionid"] = Variables.IDVERSION;
```

Here is my working snipped code  :

```
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["versionid"] = " This is a test";
```

Although, IDVERSION is a public property systematically updated in my code c#.

Has anyone an idea How to solve this problem? I think I'm near the solution.

Comment: Do you set the value of `Variables.IDVERSION` before or after assigning it to the log4net property?  Note that log4net won't track any new values you give it - you'll need to update the log4net property each time too.

Comment: I assigned the variable after in my first attempt.Now,I assigning the value of the variable before updating the log4net property..and it's working perfectly well. Simple and logical. Thanks for your help. I should think a bit more next time.:-)

Answer (score 5):

At the moment you call this:

```
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["versionid"] = Variables.IDVERSION;
```

The property will hold the value of `Variables.IDVERSION` *at that moment*. It won't automagically track updates to the `Variables.IDVERSION` variable.

So if you set `Variables.IDVERSION` later in code, you need to do the assignment to `Properties["versionid"]` again.

Comment: Good explanation. In first attempt, I assigned the variable after.  Now,I assigning the value of the variable before updating the log4net property..and it's working perfectly well. Simple and logical. Thanks for your help. I should think a bit more next time.:-)

Answer (score 0):

When log4net evaluates context properties it calls the `.ToString()` method of the property value. So you could have dynamic property values if you have a reference as a value (I believe your `idversion` field is a value type eg. Int?).

See https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/contexts.html for more details

Comment: Thanks, It was just a question of order in declaring variable first and then refreshing the log4net custom property. Working now as expected. Definitively log4net is great.