# Appending the program start time to each log line

Tags: c#, log4net

I have a program in C# and use the **log4net** library for logging.

I am trying to log the program start time in each line of log in the entire program:

```
class MyProgram
{
    static DateTime startTime;
    static void Main()
    {
        startTime = DateTime.Now;
        Log.Info(startTime + "Program started");

        MyMethod1();
        //...
    }

    static void MyMethod1()
    {
        Log.Info(startTime + "method1 step1 ");
        //code
        Log.Info(startTime + "method1 step2");
    }    
}
```

log4net configuaration

```
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="C:\Logs\\Job.json" />

      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maximumFileSize value="20MB" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.SerializedLayout, log4net.Ext.Json">
        <decorator type="log4net.Layout.Decorators.StandardTypesDecorator, log4net.Ext.Json" />
        <member value="startTime:%property{ApplicationStartTime}"/>
        <member value="date:date" />
        <member value="level:level" />
        <member value="logger:logger" />
        <member value="message:messageObject" />
        <member value="exception:exception" />
      </layout>     
    </appender>
```

Instead of appending it manually to each line, can I configure **log4net** to add the start time of the program to each log line automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a method wrapper around the log4net log method, that takes a message and forwards it to the log4net log method, but prepends the `startTime` to it for you.

```
var startTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();

void Log(string message)
{
  Log.Info($"{startTime}: {message}");
}
```

Alternatively you can create an extension method:

```
public static class LoggerExtensions
{
    public static void LogWithStartTime(this Logger self, string message)
    {
        var startTime = Global.GetStartTime();

        self.Log($"{startTime}: ${message}");
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest going with @Tewr's answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `log4net.GlobalContext` to set global properties. like this:

```
   static void Main()
    {
        log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["ApplicationStartTime"] = DateTime.Now;
    (...)
```

and then access it like this in your log configuration

```
%property{ApplicationStartTime}
```

[Here](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/contexts.html) is some more reading, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139486/log4net-how-to-add-a-custom-field-to-my-logging) is a similar question.

For `log4net.Ext.Json`, you can refer to custom properties in this manner:

```
<!-- json property named after custom property -->
<member value="ApplicationStartTime"/> 
<!-- json property with explicit name -->
<member value="startTime:ApplicationStartTime"/>
```

Comment: I tried it but I couldnt get the parameter in the logs. Added log4net config to the question